# reading a CSV file while working with template

Tags: c++

I am new to `C++` so what I am trying to do is, reading a `CSV` file in my function readRecord(`readRecord()` templated function). In my `CSV` file I have stored some data such as years and crime, crime rate etc and display it using display function. I posted my code so far but it is giving me error I am not sure about how to make it work. can someone help me out please?

```
#ifndef SICT_DATA_H
#define SICT_DATA_H
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace sict {


    const int LARGEST_NUMBER = 1000000000; // 1,000,000,000
    const int SMALLEST_NUMBER = 0;
    const int COLUMN_WIDTH = 15;

    template <typename T>

    T max(const T* data, int n)
    {
        int maximum = data[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (data[i] > maximum)
            {
                maximum = data[i];
                //*data = maximum;
            }
        }
        return maximum;
    }

    template <typename T>

    T min(const T* data, int n)
    {
        T minimum = data[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if ((dataa[i] < minimum) && (data[i] >= SMALLEST_NUMBER))
            {
                minimum = data[i];
                //*data = minimum;
            }
        }
        return minimum;
    }

    template <typename T>

    T sum(const T* data, int n)
    {
        double sum;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + data[i];
        }

        return sum;
    }

    template <typename T>

    double average(const T* data, int n)
    {
        double average;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            average = (sum(data, n) / n);
        }
        return average;
    }

    template <typename T>

    bool read(std::istream& input, T* data, int n)
    {
        char comma;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            input >> comma >> data[i];

            if (cin.fail())
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        return true;
    }

    template <typename T>

    void readRecord()
    {


        ifstream ip("crimedata.csv");
        int year[5];
        int pop[5];
        int crime[5];
        int rate[5];
        int autoo[5];
        int rate1[5];
        while (ip.EOF())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5 i++)
            {
                getline(ip.year[i], ',');
                getline(ip.pop[i], ',');
                getline(ip.crime[i], ',');
                getline(ip.rate[i], ',');
                getline(ip.autoo[i], ',');
                getline(ip.rate1[i], '\n');
                cout << year[i] << pop[i] << crime[i] << endl;
            }


        }
        ip.close;

    }


        template <typename T>

        void display(const char* name, const T* data, int n)
        {
            readRecord();
            cout << setw(20)  << name   ;
            cout << setw(15) << data   << endl;


        }
}

#endif
```

Csv File:

`5

Year    2000    2001    2002    2003    2004
Population  281421906   285317559   287973924   290788976   293656842
ViolentCrime    1425486 1439480 1423677 1383676 1360088
ViolentCrime_Rate   506.5   504.5   494.4   475.8   463.2
GrandTheftAuto  1160002 1228391 1246646 1261226 1237851
GrandTheftAuto_Rate 412.2   430.5   432.9   433.7   421.5`

Comment: What is the error? Where is an example of the csv data? Imagine you are trying to answer this question with just what is written here

Comment: There don't seem to be any commas in your input file. And looping on eof is almost never what you want to do. It checks for end of file before you read and potentially find the end of file. Plus there are many more things that can go wrong than just hitting the end of the file that you need to address.